# TicTacToe with AI in ruby - follow-up overload

Tags: ruby, tic-tac-toe, ai

I already posted this program numerous times, always surprised by the amount of improvement that is possible suggested by people here. Is it possible to make it even better, without nitpicking? At this point this is a special curiosity of mine =).

```
# win sequences constant
WIN_SEQUENCES = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8],
                 [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],
                 [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]

# the game board
class Board
  attr_accessor :cells

  def initialize
    @cells = Array.new(9) # { nil }
  end

  def as_string
    stringed_board = @cells.map.with_index do |symbol, idx|
      symbol || idx + 1
    end

    stringed_board.each_slice(3).map do |row|
      "  #{row.join(' | ')}"
    end.join("\n ---+---+---\n")
  end

  def cell_open?(position)
    @cells[position - 1].nil?
  end

  def win_game?(symbol)
    WIN_SEQUENCES.any? do |seq|
      return true if seq.all? { |a| @cells[a] == symbol }
    end
  end

  def full?
    @cells.all?
  end

  def place_symbol(position, symbol)
    @cells[position - 1] = symbol
  end
end

# game logic
class Game
  def initialize
    @board = Board.new
    # default states
    @player1 = Human.new(@board, 'Player 1', 'X')
    @player2 = AI.new(@board, 'Evil AI', 'O')
    welcome_msg
    start_screen
  end

  private

  def start_screen(choice = gets.chomp)
    until (1..3).include?(choice)
      exit if choice.downcase == 'exit'
      select_game_mode(choice.to_i)
    end
  end

  def select_game_mode(choice)
    case choice
    when 1 then [@player2 = Human.new(@board, 'Player 2', 'O')]
    when 3 then [@player1 = AI.new(@board, 'Kind AI', 'X'),
                 @player2 = AI.new(@board, 'Evil AI', 'O')]
    else puts 'You silly goose, try again.'
    end
    @current_player = @player2
    display_board
    run_game
  end

  def welcome_msg
    print "\nWelcome to Tic Tac Toe.\n\n"
    puts 'Enter 1 to play against another player, 2 to play against an evil AI'\
         ', 3 to watch evil AI play against kind AI.'
    puts 'Type EXIT anytime to quit.'
  end

  def display_board
    puts "\e[H\e[2J" # ANSI clear
    print @board.as_string, "\n\n"
  end

  def run_game
    until game_over?
      swap_players
      check_and_place
      display_board
      display_result
    end
  end

  def game_over?
    @board.win_game?(@current_player.symbol) || @board.full?
  end

  def check_and_place
    position = @current_player.take_input
    @board.place_symbol(position.to_i, @current_player.symbol) unless position.nil?
  end

  def display_result
    if @board.win_game?(@current_player.symbol)
      puts "Game Over, #{@current_player.name} has won."
      exit
    elsif @board.full?
      puts 'Draw.'
      exit
    end
  end

  def swap_players
    case @current_player
    when @player1 then @current_player = @player2
    else               @current_player = @player1
    end
  end
end

# human players in the game
class Human
  attr_reader :name, :symbol

  def initialize(board, name, symbol)
    @board = board
    @name = name
    @symbol = symbol
  end

  def take_input(input = nil)
    until (1..9).include?(input) && @board.cell_open?(input)
      puts "Choose a number (1-9) to place your mark #{name}."
      input = validate_input(gets.chomp)
    end
    input
  end

  private

  def validate_input(input)
    if input.to_i == 0
      exit if input.downcase == 'exit'
      puts 'You can\'t use a string, silly.'
    else
      position = validate_position(input.to_i)
    end
    position
  end

  def validate_position(position)
    if !(1..9).include? position
      puts 'This position does not exist, chief.'
      puts 'Try again or type EXIT to, well, exit.'
    elsif !@board.cell_open? position
      puts 'Nice try but this cell is already taken.'
      puts 'Try again or type EXIT to, well, exit.'
    end
    position
  end
end

# AI players in the game
class AI
  attr_reader :name, :symbol, :board

  def initialize(board, name, symbol)
    @board = board
    @name = name
    @symbol = symbol
  end

  def take_input
    loading_simulation
    check_win
    return @finished if @finished
    check_block
    return @finished if @finished
    check_defaults
    return @finished if @finished
    # failsafe check
    (1..9).reverse_each { |i| return i if board.cells[i - 1].nil? }
  end

  private

  # first check if possible to win before human player.
  def check_win
    @finished = false
    1.upto(9) do |i|
      origin = board.cells[i - 1]
      board.cells[i - 1] = symbol if origin.nil?
      # put it there if AI can win that way.
      return @finished = i if board.win_game?(symbol)
      board.cells[i - 1] = origin
    end
  end

  def other_symbol
    case symbol
    when 'X' then 'O'
    else 'X'
    end
  end

  # if impossible to win before player,
  # check if possible to block player from winning.
  def check_block
    @finished = false
    1.upto(9) do |i|
      origin = board.cells[i - 1]
      board.cells[i - 1] = other_symbol if origin.nil?
      # put it there if player can win that way.
      return @finished = i if board.win_game?(other_symbol)
      board.cells[i - 1] = origin
    end
  end

  # if impossible to win nor block, default placement to center.
  # if occupied, choose randomly between corners or sides.
  def check_defaults
    @finished = false
    if board.cells[4].nil?
      @finished = 5
    else
      rand < 0.51 ? possible_sides : possible_corners
    end
  end

  def possible_sides
    [2, 4, 6, 8].each do |i|
      return @finished = i if board.cells[i - 1].nil?
    end
  end

  def possible_corners
    [1, 3, 7, 9].each do |i|
      return @finished = i if board.cells[i - 1].nil?
    end
  end

  def loading_simulation
    str = "\r#{name} is scheming"
    10.times do
      print str += '.'
      sleep(0.1)
    end
  end
end

Game.new
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to analyze each class in your code separately.
`Board` - update certain methods:

```
def as_string
  stringed_board = @cells.map.with_index(1) { |symbol, index| symbol || index }
#..... 
end

def cell_open?(position)
  !@cells[position - 1]  # personal preference to use '!'
end

def win_game?(symbol)
  WIN_SEQUENCES.any? do |seq|
    seq.all? { |c| @cells[c] == symbol }
    # not necessary to return true explicitly
  end
end
```

Duplication in classes `Human` and `AI`(`attr_reader`s and `initialize` method). I suggest to move it to parent class (call it `Player`):

```
class Player
  attr_reader :name, :symbol

  def initialize(board, name, symbol)
    @board, @name, @symbol = board, name, symbol
  end
end

class Human < Player
  # code without initialize method and attr_accessors
end

class AI < Player
  attr_reader :board
  # code ...
end
```

`AI` class:

```
class AI < Player
  attr_reader :board

  def take_input
    loading_simulation
    check_win_or_block(symbol) || check_win_or_block(other_symbol) || check_defaults
    # there was a lot of duplication here (with unnecessary explicit returns)
  end

  private

  def check_win_or_block(sym)
  # check_win and check_block have same logic and
  # can be replaced with one method
    finished = false
    0.upto(8) do |i|
      origin = board.cells[i]
      board.cells[i] = sym if !origin
      finished = i + 1 if board.win_game?(sym)
      board.cells[i] = origin
    end
    finished
  end

  def other_symbol
    symbol == 'X' ? 'O' : 'X' # I'm using ternary operator in such cases
  end

  def check_defaults
    # @finished variable is unnecessary now
    # possible_slides and possible_corners are pieces with the same logic
    # I replace them with possible_position that passes block
    if board.cells[4]
      rand < 0.51 ? possible_position(&:even?) : possible_position(&:odd?)
    else
      5
    end
  end

  def possible_position(&block)
    result = (1..9).select(&block).each do |i|
      return i + 1 if !board.cells[i]
    end
    result.is_a?(Integer) ? result : board.cells.rindex(nil) + 1
    # this line takes functionality of your code (take_input method):
    # (1..9).reverse_each { |i| return i if board.cells[i - 1].nil? }
  end

  def loading_simulation
    str = "\r#{name} is scheming"
    10.times { print str += '.'; sleep(0.1) }
  end
end
```

Class `Game`:

```
class Game
  def initialize
    # ..... 
    @player2 = AI.new(@board, 'Evil AI', 'O')
    @current_player = @player2
    # current_player is not a part of select_game_mode method functionality
    welcome_msg
    start_screen
  end

  private

  def start_screen(choice = gets)
    choice.strip!.downcase! if choice
  # In your code use until loop is not working. Reason:
  # 'gets' must be placed inside of this loop
    until %w(1 2 3 exit).include?(choice)
  # (1..3).include?(choice) in your code will always return false
  # because choice is a String
      puts 'You silly goose, try again.'
      start_screen(gets)
    end
    select_game_mode(choice)
    display_board
    run_game
  end

  def select_game_mode(choice)
    case choice
    when '1' then @player2 = Human.new(@board, 'Player 2', 'O')
    when '3' then @player1 = AI.new(@board, 'Kind AI', 'X')
    # @player2 = ... removed - it's already set.
    when 'exit' then exit
  # exit option must be here (I think).
    end
  end

 # ....

  def run_game
    until game_over?
      swap_players
      check_and_place
      display_board
      if game_over?
        puts display_result
        exit
   # exit moved from display_result. It changes state of program but not displaying result
      end
    end
  end

 # .....

  def display_result
  # It's "bad" style to place business logic and UI in one method.
  # code is not clear and harder to test
  # all puts's moved to run_game_method
    if @board.win_game?(@current_player.symbol)
      "Game Over, #{@current_player.name} has won."
    elsif @board.full?
      'Draw.'
    end
  end

  def swap_players
    @current_player = @current_player == @player1 ? @player2 : @player1
    # It's not essentially, but looks better.
  end

end
```

Overall, try not to mix business logic in your code with input/output functionality.

That's it for now. Will update my answer later.

Comment: BTW I think `choice = gets.chomp.downcase` is better then recursion in `#start_screen`

Comment: Your modifications for the first two methods seem to worsen the code readability without giving value back (e.g. performance). Player separation: nice catch! Didn't know you could do that with inheritance. AI class: I like your thinking here. I think you meant 0..8 instead of 1..8 in the default check. Game: nice, I missed it (`select_game_mode` was always executed anyway, oops).
I wrote a comment before but was wrong about the `finished` variable.

Comment: You need recursion in #start_screen. In your variant of this method if `choise == '5'` function exits from `until`-loop and start default game. Gets inside `until`-loop will ask user for input "until gets" expected result.

Comment: About `as_string` and `cell_open?`. Difference in readability is unnoticeable. In #as_string method you've used `with_index` and it has 'original' possibility to pass starting index. Why not use it?
How you estimate performance?
I've write benchmark to compare original and modified methods. Results: (for as_string) * 1_000_000:
                 user system total   real
updated 14.806 0.004 14.81 14.8432016
original 14.966 0.004 14.97 15.0057298
Results: (for cell_open?) * 100_000_000:
original   18.524 0         18.524 18.5476748
updated  16.39 0.004 16.394 16.4081238

Comment: "I think you meant 0..8 instead of 1..8 in the default check." - my typo. Method returns position (from 1 to 9), not index in `@cells` array. Must be:
`result = (1..9).select(&block).each do |i|`

Comment: `choice = gets.chomp.downcase until %w(1 2 3 exit).include?(choice)` will work, try it. In readability I mean 2 things: 1. `!something` is confusing to read just by itself, might aswell use `unless` or just be explicit. Your #as_string is a borderline case, it's a bit too long for ruby style guidelines.