# Ruby Command Line Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: ruby, game, console, tic-tac-toe

The following is my implementation of a command-line Tic-Tac-Toe game, written in Ruby. This was my first attempt at practicing object-oriented design principles.

```
require 'colored'

module TicTacToe
  class Player 
    attr_accessor :symbol
    def initialize(symbol)
      @symbol = symbol
    end
  end

  class Board 
    attr_reader :spaces
    def initialize
      @spaces = Array.new(9)
    end

    def to_s
      output = ""
      0.upto(8) do |position|
        output << "#{spaces[position] || position}"
        case position % 3 
        when 0, 1 then output << " | "
        when 2 then output << "\n-----------\n" unless position == 8
        end
      end
      output
    end

    def check_space(cell, sym)
      if spaces[cell].nil?
        place_symbol(cell, sym)
        @current_turn += 1
      else
        puts "Space unavailable! Please select another cell"
      end
    end

    def place_symbol(cell, sym)
      spaces[cell] = sym
    end

    WINNING_COMBOS = [
      [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8],
      [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],
      [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]
    ]

    def winning_scenarios
      WINNING_COMBOS.each do |set|
        if spaces[set[0]] == spaces[set[1]] && spaces[set[1]] == spaces[set[2]]
          return true unless spaces[set[0]].nil?
        end
      end
      false
    end

    def tie
      if !spaces.include?(nil) && !winning_scenarios
        return true
      end
    end
  end

  class Game < Board
    attr_reader :player1, :player2, :symbol
    def initialize
      super
      play_game
    end

    def play_game
      @player1 = Player.new("X")
      @player2 = Player.new("O")
      puts Board.new
      @current_turn = 1
      turn
      win_message
      tie_message
      play_again
    end

    def move(player)
      while !winning_scenarios && !tie
        puts "Where would you like to move 'player #{player.symbol}'?".red
        choice = gets.chomp.to_i
        check_space(choice, player.symbol)
        puts "Player #{player.symbol}'s move:".green
        puts self
        turn
      end
    end

    def tie_message
      puts "It's a Draw!".cyan if tie
    end

    def win_message
      puts "Game over!".cyan if winning_scenarios
    end

    def turn
      @current_turn.even? ? move(@player2) : move(@player1)
    end

    def play_again
      puts "Play again? (yes or no)".yellow
      answer = gets.chomp.downcase
      if answer == "yes"
        TicTacToe::Game.new
      else
        puts "Goodbye".cyan.bold
      end
    end
  end
end

TicTacToe::Game.new
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not bad.

### Unbounded recursion

Inside the `Game` class:

> ```
> def initialize
>   # ...
>   play_game
> end
>
> def play_game
>   @player1 = Player.new("X")
>   @player2 = Player.new("O")
>   # ...
>   play_again
> end
>
> def play_again
>   # ...
>   if answer == "yes"
>     TicTacToe::Game.new
>   else
>     # ...
>   end
> end
> ```

You're using recursion to repeat the game, which can get arbitrarily deep, leading to a stack overflow error. Use a loop instead. Also, to avoid violating the Single Responsibility Principle, put this loop outside the `Game` class whose sole responsibility should be to play a game.

Don't call `play_again` in `play_game`, and move `play_again` outside the class. The main code should be:

```
def play_again?
  puts "Play again? (yes or no)".yellow
  answer = gets.chomp.downcase
  return answer == "yes"
end

loop do
  TicTacToe::Game.new
  unless play_again?
    puts "Goodbye".cyan.bold
    break
  end
end
```

(I renamed `play_again` to `play_again?`. It's conventional to use a question mark in names of methods that return a boolean)

### Unbounded recursion 2

> ```
> def turn
>   @current_turn.even? ? move(@player2) : move(@player1)
> end
>
> def move(player)
>   while !winning_scenarios && !tie
>     # ...
>     turn
>   end
> end
> ```

This recursion is not bounded either (it's not bounded by the number of spaces in the board, because a function call occurs for (rejected) invalid moves too). Use a loop instead:

```
def play_game
  # ...
  while !winning_scenarios && !tie
    turn
  end
  # ...
end

def turn
  @current_turn.even? ? move(@player2) : move(@player1)
end

def move(player)
  # ...
  # Don't call turn here
end
```

### Object oriented design

> ```
> class Board; ...; end
>
> class Game < Board; ...; end
> ```

A game is not a board. A game *has* a board. Use composition instead of inheritance:

```
class Game # NOTE: Don't inherit Board
  def initialize
    @board = Board.new # NOTE
    play_game
  end

  def play_game
    # ...
    while !@board.winning_scenarios && !@board.tie
      turn
    end
    # ...
  end

  def move(player)
    # ...
    space_available = @board.check_space(choice, player.symbol)
    @current_turn += 1 if space_available
    puts "Player #{player.symbol}'s move:".green
    puts @board # NOTE
  end

  def tie_message
    ... if @board.tie
  end

  def win_message
    ... if @board.winning_scenarios
  end

  # ...
end
```

Note I moved `@current_turn += 1` to `Game`. A game has a current turn, a board doesn't. Modify `check_space` so it returns a boolean.

### Encapsulation

Make internal methods private, so they aren't visible outside the class:

```
class Board 
  def initialize; ...; end
  def to_s; ...; end
  def check_space(cell, sym); ...; end
  def winning_scenarios; ...; end
  def tie; ...; end

  private

    WINNING_COMBOS = [
      [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8],
      [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],
      [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]
    ]

    def place_symbol(cell, sym); ...; end
      spaces[cell] = sym
    end
end

class Game
  def initialize; ...; end
  def play_game; ...; end

  private

    def move(player); ...; end
    def tie_message; ...; end
    def win_message; ...; end
    def turn; ...; end
end
```

Remove this line which exposes internal fields of `Game`: (you never actually use `Game#symbol`, by the way)

```
attr_reader :player1, :player2, :symbol
```

And this line from `Board`: (then change every occurence of `spaces` in `Board` to `@spaces`)

```
attr_reader :spaces
```

### Board methods

> ```
> def check_space(cell, sym)
>   if @spaces[cell].nil?
>     place_symbol(cell, sym)
>   else
>     puts "Space unavailable! Please select another cell"
>   end
> end
> ```

- **Single Responsibility Principle:** `Board` should not do any printing, as it's not its core responsibility. It's better to return a boolean instead and let `Game` do the printing.
- **Naming:** This method both checks if the space is free *and* places a symbol. Rename it to `place_symbol_if_free`.
- **Naming 2:** Use `position` instead of `cell` to be consistent with other methods.
- Consider splitting this to two methods: `space_free?(position)` and `place_symbol(position, sym)` (already exists) and then call both from `Game`.

> ```
> WINNING_COMBOS = [
>   [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8],
>   [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],
>   [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]
> ]
> ```

Put this inside `winning_scenarios`, the only method where it's used.

> ```
> def winning_scenarios
>   WINNING_COMBOS.each do |set|
>     if @spaces[set[0]] == @spaces[set[1]] && @spaces[set[1]] == @spaces[set[2]]
>       return true unless @spaces[set[0]].nil?
>     end
>   end
>   false
> end
> ```

- Rename `winning_scenarios` to `game_won?`. Or to `winner` and return the winner's symbol
- Use `Array#any?` instead of looping.
- Use `Array#map` to obtain the symbols at the locations of a set, instead of repeatedly accessing `@spaces`.

Result:

```
def winner
  WINNING_COMBOS.any? do |set|
    symbols = set.map { |position| @spaces[position] }
    if symbols[0] == symbols[1] && symbols[1] == symbols[2]
      symbols[0]
    end
  end
end
```

> ```
> def tie
>   if !@spaces.include?(nil) && !winning_scenarios
>     return true
>   end
> end
> ```

Rename to `tie?`, and simply return the boolean:

```
def tie?
  return !@spaces.include?(nil) && !winner
end
```

I also suggets extracting first part to a new private method `full?`.

`to_s` can be simplified by using functional programming. See my implementation of `as_string` in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/108961/tictactoe-game-with-functional-ai-in-ruby-follow-up/108983#108983).

### Game methods

#### `play_game`

> ```
> puts Board.new
> ```

Change this to `puts @board`.

> ```
> while !@board.winner && !@board.tie?
> ```

Looks like `Board` is missing a `game_over?` method.

> ```
> win_message
> tie_message
> ```

These method names are misleading. Each one *conditionally* prints a message. Merge them to a single `print_game_result` method.

#### `turn`

> ```
> def turn
>   @current_turn.even? ? move(@player2) : move(@player1)
> end
> ```

The call to `move` is duplicated because the method does two things: (1) determine who's turn it is (2) call `move`.

It's better to do only the first one:

```
def current_player
  @current_turn.even? ? @player2 : @player1
end
```

Then use `move(current_player)` in `play_game`.

#### `move`

> ```
> def move(player)
>   puts "Where would you like to move 'player #{player.symbol}'?".red
>   choice = gets.chomp.to_i
>   space_available = @board.check_space(choice, player.symbol)
>   @current_turn += 1 if space_available
>   puts "Player #{player.symbol}'s move:".green
>   puts @board
> end
> ```

I'd move the last two `puts` statements to `play_game`, because they're not part of making a move.

If you split `check_space` as I suggest earlier, you can make a loop that gets input until `Board#space_free?` returns true and then call `Board#place_symbol`. Otherwise, you'll have to rename this method to `try_make_a_move`.

#### `initialize`

Don't call `game_play`. Constructors should only initialize an object, and should not do IO. Instead, call `game_play` in the main code (`TicTacToe::Game.new.play_game`).

### Further Improvements

- Say who won.
- Use digits 1 to 9 when printing the board and getting user input. It's hard to tell `0` and `O` apart.

Comment: Just wow! @Spike thank you so much for pouring through this and making thoughtful comments and suggestions. I will work through your suggestions and make adjustments where necessary. Thanks again.